# Odd Mesos UI behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mesos

I have deployed a system in my AWS account and noticed a behavior I don't quite understand. My other systems are fine, but there's something about this environment that forces incorrect machine listed as a slave.

In the first image I have a screenshot of the slaves tab. You'll see that Slave host name is `ip-10-184-241-84.ec2.internal`, as shown below:

[image: screenshot 1]

When I click on the ID I see `Slave:ip-10-184-241-166.ec2.internal`, which in fact is the address of the master, no resources are showing either:

[image: screenshot 2]

Any ideas on what might be causing this behavior?

Thank you!

See this problem in this environment with both Mesos 0.25 and 0.28.

Answer (score 0):

Traced the issue down to port 5051 not being opened between two Security Groups. After I updated the rules Mesos looks as expected.